# OpenGL ES 3.2: is it possible to use multisample rasterization without a multisample target?

Tags: opengl-es, fragment-shader

I want to access `gl_SampleMaskIn` (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/html/gl_SampleMaskIn.xhtml) in the fragment shader to get an approximation of the coverage value of the currently shaded pixel - but beyond that I don't want the fragment shader output to be written to a multi-sample target. Is this possible? Can the rasterizer generate a coverage mask if the bound target is not a multisample one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone else is looking for the same:

EXT_raster_multisample and NV_framebuffer_mixed_samples provide this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do this.

The OpenGL ES API doesn't allow control over the rasterizer sample count separately from the framebuffer attachment sample count.

Comment: This is a comment, but not an answer

Comment: Not even with extended OpenGL es?

Comment: @Rabbid76
- I think it's borderline (see, e.g. [How is this answer consisting only of "NO"s an answer, or am I missing something?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326031/1364007)). In [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32174664) I chose "Looks OK" as it does answer the question. It'd be better if the answer said *why* it's not possible, but that's outside the purview of the Low quality answers review queue.

Comment: In terms of quality of answer, I'm not sure what more useful information I can add. Added some more context, but it doesn't really change the meat of the answer ...

Comment: It's actually wrong as I found out in the meantime (at least regarding extended OpenGL). EXT_raster_multisample and NV_framebuffer_mixed_samples both provide this functionality

Comment: I stand corrected. You can do this on 0.25% of OpenGL ES 3.2 devices (those with Nvidia hardware). No other OpenGL ES 3.2 hardware vendor implements these extensions AFAICT, so for all practical purposes the answer is still "you can't do this" unless you get to choose the device you are running on.